# How to ignore undefined excel cells while parsing through xlsx module of node.js

Tags: node.js, excel, xlsx

I am parsing foo.xls file , while parsing excel in between some undefined cells are present where it leads to error.
here desired value is undefined since `.v` does not hold any value

```
if(typeof require !== 'undefined'); 
 XLSX =require('xlsx');
 XLSX.readFile('C:/Users/Automation_tool/ip_filtering.xls');
 var REGRESSION_IPV6 =  workbook.SheetNames[3];
 var l = 2;
 for( ; l < 30; l++)
 {
        var address_of_cell = 'G'+l;
        /* Get worksheet */
        var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[REGRESSION_IPV6];
        var desired_cell = worksheet[address_of_cell];
    if(desired_cell != 'undefined')// this condition is not working
    {
        var desired_value = desired_cell.v;
        if ((desired_value == 'Pass')&&(l == 29))
        {
            console.log('PASS IPV6');
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Could you show your loop structure? Please elaborate what you mean with "ignore". What do you want to do if you can't find a cell?

Comment: when i am parsing excel cells , there are some undefined cells in between say 'G' column. suppose I am parsing G column and G10 cell is undefined then 'desired_cell.v' give error saying 'Cannot read property 'v' of undefined'. I don't know how to handle that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with excel. `undefined` is a literal. If you put it in quotes (`'` or `"`) you are comparing to the string that contains `undefined`, which is different.

Change your check to `if(desired_cell != undefined)` (you know that you are also checking for `null` if you write it like that, right?)

Comment: then mark it as ”answered”. The question will show up in other folks “unanswered question” filters.